# How to display the list of tasks that gradle can currently execute in the console

Tags: gradle

When I create a gradle project, how do I know which built-in tasks it has?

gradle 5.4

Just create a new java project

I want display the list of tasks in console,but i can't

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the following files in your project:

```
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle
```

Simply execute `./gradlew tasks --all` to list all available tasks that you can execute. `gradlew.bat` if you're on Windows.